# How to use an atribbute of an object Many To Many?

Tags: django

I'm using Django 2.1

I've got these 2 `models` with a `ManyToMany` relationship:

```
class Ingrediente(models.Model):
produtor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=10)
nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
descricao = models.TextField()
quantidade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
```

e

```
class Produto(models.Model):
nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
descricao = models.TextField()
ingredientes = models.ManyToManyField(Ingrediente)
utilitarios = models.ManyToManyField(OutrosCustos)

def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
```

I use the this `view` to return a list with all objects of Class Produto:

```
def produtos_list(request):
produtos = Produto.objects.filter()
return render(request, 'egg_app/produtos_list.html', {'produtos':produtos})
```

And in my template I write this:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nº Produto</th>
        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
        <th scope="col">Ingredientes</th>
        <th scope="col">Custo</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for p in produtos %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ p.pk }}</th>
            <td>{{ p.nome }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.ingredientes }}</td>
            <td>custo teste</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

But my result in the column `Ingredientes` has been `egg_app.Ingrediente.None` and not the name of the Ingrediente of the relationship (between `Ingrediente` and `Produto`). In my Django admin page, I associate this, so I'm sure about the relationship.

Comment: There isn't "an" ingredient. It's a many to many relationship. There are *several*. You need to iterate through `p.ingredientes.all`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Now I have "<QuerySet [<Ingrediente: Ingrediente Teste 1>, <Ingrediente: Ingrediente Teste 2>]>", any tip to return just de name?

Comment: `p.ingredientes.values_list('nome', flat=True)` gives you a queryset with just the names. You can then loop through it, or convert it to a comma-separated string etc.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hei, sorry, but can you give me a example of this code? I tried to use p.ingredientes.values_list('nome', flat=True) but I had a syntax error

Comment: update: I got it. I'll post an answer here to document this